# MVC3 call Ajax in Jquery for store value in database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating MVC3 Application 
My view Page script code is-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnClaimCheck').click(function () {
            var slvals = []
            $('input:checkbox[name=ChkCheckClaim]:checked').each(function () {
                if ($('#ClaimSelectStatus').val() == "XYZABCZ") {
                    alert("bikaner")

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("CheckClaim")',
                        type: 'POST',
                       // data: { comment: $("#UpdatelabelName").val(prompt("Please Eenter Details","Rejected Without reason")) }
                        data: { comment: prompt("Please Enter Details", "Rejected Without reason")
                        }


                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert("other")

                }
            });

        });
    });                                                                                           
</script>
```

and my controler is -

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CheckClaim(String comment)
        {
                return View();
           }
```

its working and breakpoint hit on controler method but inside controler when i try to call any method from model then it can't hit the controller method and not show any error .

Comment: What is the purpose of `prompt("Please Enter Details", "Rejected Without reason")`

Comment: You've also got a redundant comma after prompt()

Comment: @Satpal  use prompt to pass data from user side and pass it to contoller

Comment: @Fresh - redundant comma i have changed earlier but its not working

Comment: For testing purposes, have you tried removing the call to prompt and just tried posting back a simple string e.g, 'Hello'? Also are you getting any errors in your browser debug console?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good place for the prompt.
**even though it is working**  http://jsfiddle.net/j6PVm/1

Please replace it with a string like

```
data: {comment : "mydata"}
```

this is just to see that the ajax is functioning.

in general the prompt should be outside of the `$.ajax` scope.

$('#btnClaimCheck').click(function () {
var data = prompt("Please Enter Details", "Rejected Without reason");

```
$.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("CheckClaim")',
         type: 'POST',
         data: { comment: data}
      });
});
```